# Translate SQL Server CREATE TABLE into Access

Tags: ms-access, ddl

How do I translate this into an Access `create table`?

```sql
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    EmployeeKey INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName nvarChar(25) NOT NULL,
    MiddleName nvarChar(25) NULL,
    LastName nVarChar(25) NOT NULL,
    Title nVarChar(100) null,
    ManagerKey INT NULL REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeKey),
    CreatedDate DateTime NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    UpdatedDate DateTime NULL
)
```

Comment: Sure, I use it all the time in SQL Server. You just have to mark the column as nullable so you can insert the first row.

Comment: Having just `NULL` by itself seems to be working fine in my partial answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I constructed this DDL statement in the Access Immediate window:

```vb
strDdl = "CREATE TABLE Employee (" & _
    "EmployeeKey IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, " & _
    "FirstName TEXT(25) NOT NULL, " & _
    "MiddleName TEXT(25), " & _
    "LastName TEXT(25) NOT NULL, " & _
    "Title TEXT(100), " & _
    "ManagerKey LONG REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeKey), " & _
    "CreatedDate DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(), " & _
    "UpdatedDate DATETIME);"
```

Since it includes the keyword `DEFAULT` it must be executed from ADO/OleDb.

```vb
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strDdl
```

That statement executed successfully as shown.  It would fail if executed from DAO --- *"Run-time error '3292': Syntax error in field definition."*

---

Notes:

- TEXT is equivalent to NVARCHAR
- CHAR is equivalent to NCHAR and will result in padded strings

Comment: Yeah, I didn't make that clear.  It should succeed using OleDb regardless of client code language.  And ADO is based on OleDb.